# How to browse through directories in a tree like structure in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line

Is there a program to browse through directories in a tree like structure in the linux terminal?

Example:

Suppose I was at `/home/username/mysite` and typed `command_I_am_looking_for` then I would get: (similar behavior as the `tree` program in Linux)

```
mysite
|-- manage.py
|-- mysite
|-- polls   
|-- templates
```

Then there should be a selection highlighter (say a different color of the currently highlighted folder). Suppose that this selection highlighter was standing on the `polls` directory. After pushing `<enter>` I would get this:

```
mysite
    |-- manage.py
    |-- mysite
    |-- polls   
          |-- __init__.py
          |-- models.py
          |-- tests.py
          |-- views.py
          |-- static
    |-- templates
```

It should be possible to just keep on going further in the directories, only unfolding them when selected and pushing `<enter>`. If I pushed a certain key, say `s` then I would select that directory and change my current directory path into that path.

Is there such a program?

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but have you ever tried `mc` - midnight commander?

Comment: Thnx. Could you make a seperate answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but have you ever tried `mc` - the midnight commander?

Comment: I have checked `mc`, but I prefer `vifm` for now. It uses by default g,h,j,k instead of arrow keys (as in `vim`). The interface is also seems a bit simpler. Also check: http://tuxarena.blogspot.be/2009/04/10-file-managers-for-linux.html

Comment: Also check ranger: http://ranger.nongnu.org/

Answer (score 2):

IMHO [Ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/) is a better option and it has vi like bindings

Comment: You are my hero today! I have been looking for a utility like this for quite some time. It is not exactly a tree but still very useful. I wish I read your post 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

use tree command

If it is not installed in your system then install with this procdure.

First go to root

> [max@avi ~]$ su -
>
> Password:

then in the terminal type this command

> [root@avi ~]# yum install tree

once it installed type this command in the terminal

> [max@avi ~]$ tree

Comment: I already work with tree, but you can only print out directory structures, not browse through them right?